# AX2012 Sharedtypes schema missing from imported schema

Tags: schema, biztalk, axapta, edi

I've received a schema from a customer, which contains a reference to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes" with a schema named "SharedTypes.xsd".

I am new to AX, so I'm not sure how I go about finding this schema. I looked around online and found this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769362.aspx, but I am not able to view the schema in Biztalk. Is it possible to find this schema online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also receive this schema from your customer since it always contains the definition of complex data types. You *may* find one online, but you will miss every customization in AX for your customer implementation and all custom data types as well. Knowing AX, there is always customization work done. I have yet to encounter an AX which uses plain standard.

Ask your customer for the file, without it, your integration will not work.

Be aware however: this file is subject to a lot of changes when dealing with ongoing AX development. If the AX implementation is just starting out, try to have a version number in there somewhere. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have asked the customer to send the schema.